# Nodejs sequlize find all query

Tags: node.js, sequelize-typescript

Is it possible to pass multiple values to find all query
Here is the information:
I do have a data values as :

```
[
{ "Id":"21"},
{ "Id":"22"},
{ "Id":"23"},
{ "Id":"24"},
{ "Id":"25"},]
```

Is it possible to pass these above values to :
`await model.findall{where:{Id:......}})`

How can I implement the multiple data values

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array directly to the where option to implicitly use the IN operator:

```js
await model.findAll({
  where: {
    id: [21, 22, 23] // Same as using `id: { [Op.in]: [21, 22, 23] }`
  }
});
```